# Solving Recurrence Relations 3

Tags: recurrence-relation

Consider the following recurrence
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+n\log n$$

My approach:
Solving using Substitution
$T(n)=n \log n+(n-1) \log (n-1)+(n-2) \log (n-2)+(n-3) \log (n-3)+...$

$=[n\log n + n \log(n-1)+ n \log(n-2)+ n \log(n-3)+...]-[\log(n-1)+2\log(n-2)+3\log(n-3)+...]$

$=[n(\log n + \log(n-1)+ \log(n-2)+ \log(n-3)+...)]-[\log(n-1)+2\log(n-2)+3\log(n-3)+...]$

$=[n(\log(n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+...)]-[\log(n-1)+2\log(n-2)+3\log(n-3)+...]$

$=[n(\log n!)]-[\log(n-1)+2\log(n-2)+3\log(n-3)+...]$

$\approx O(n^2 \log n)$

But ans is given as $O(n \log n)$. What have I done wrong

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  $O(n \log n)$ is wrong.  This is easily shown by considering the sum of $j \log j$ over $j=n/2,\dots,n-1,n$; each term is at least $\frac12 n \log (n/2)$, and there are $n/2$ terms, so the total sum is at least $\frac14 n^2 \log(n/2)$, which is $\Theta(n^2 \log n)$.